# I tried running this code , no output on emulator nor any error. Cant make the menu pop up what to do?

Tags: android, menu

```
package com.guess.phone;

import android.app.Activity;

public class Menu extends Activity {

    // Setting Up the MenuInflater

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu Menu) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu((android.view.Menu) Menu);

            MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();    
            awesome.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,(android.view.Menu) Menu);
            return true; 
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSweet:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.guess.phone.SWEET"));
            return true;
        case R.id.menuToast:
            return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(android.view.Menu) Menu` should just be `menu`

Comment: @Blundell that gives me error because i have capitalized M in the Menu class as per java notation when i put 'Menu' eclipse thinks i am trying to refer to the parameter whereas i wanted to refer to sdk MENU class

Comment: what other possibilities are there for it to not work.

Comment: as @Blundell suggested change Menu to menu or some other name, even if it is logically correct, it is quite confusing to everyone and more code to you in the way of typecasting. and you need to refer to the parameter and not the menu class

Comment: @nandeesh  i tried what you gave me but the problem with that code still exist what i did was

Comment: public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, (android.view.Menu) menu);
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu((android.view.Menu) menu);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use below OnCreateOptionsMenu instead

```
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```